# Exporting selected features in geopandas - GeoPackage vs SHP

Tags: export, geopandas, geopackage

I have a polygon layer representing buildings as a SHP and GeoPackage.

I am selecting a subset of these polygons and save it in a selected.txt file containing something like "gid=65 or gid=562 or ....". When I copy and paste this statement in QGIS when SHP is opened, it correctly selects the features; whereas if the GeoPackage is opened it fails to select (no feature is selected).

In addition, I tried to select these features in Python, it again failed for GeoPackage:

```
import geopandas as gpd
data = dict()
i1 = "selected.txt"
f1 = open(i1, "r")
f1_select = f1.readlines()
data['osm'] = gpd.read_file('osm.gpkg', where = f1_select)
```

When I update the statement that selects about 500 features out of 2K to selecting only a few in QGIS, it again works for GeoPackage. Any workarounds for this bug so that I can select and export hundreds of features for a GeoPackage layer in Python?

Comment: The selected features: "gid=65 or gid=25291 or gid=25293 or ....".

Comment: Would that be possible to realise this within a data frame selection? (e.g. selected_gids = set(65, 25291, 25293) data[(data['gid'] in selected_gids)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the following code works. The trick was to use the [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function:

```py
data[eval(q_selected_polygons)].to_file("selected.shp")
```

where `q_selected_polygons` is generated within a loop that has the following structure:

> ```
> "(data['gid'] == 65) | (data['gid'] == 25291) | (data['gid'] == 25293)
> | ..."
> ```

the last or symbol (i.e. `|`) must be deleted after the for loop.

This code seems to work on Shapefile and does not work for GeoPackage.

Answer (score 0):

First a small issue in the sample code: when you use `readlines()`, a list of strings is returned, one for each line in the file, rather than a single string. Even if there is only one line in the file, it will be a list with a single element. The `where` parameter expects a single string.

However, apparently if there are > ~900 OR's, a "failed to prepare SQL" error seems to be thrown, probably because there is a limit on the number of OR's.

You can solve it by using an IN filter rather than the OR's. I tested that way up to 50.000 elements without problems:

```
gid IN (65,562,...)
```

Script:

```
import geopandas as gpd
data = dict()
i1 = "selected.txt"
f1 = open(i1, "r")
f1_select = f1.read()
data['osm'] = gpd.read_file('osm.gpkg', where=f1_select)
```